# Angular routing with 2 path parameters in child

Tags: angular

I'm currently having my Java course and have to deal with UI with Angular. That's why I can misunderstand some things. The structure of my application is following: some classroom has a list of announcements, and each announcement has list of comments. With *http://localhost:4200/classrooms/3* I access the classroom page with its description and list of announcements. Then I want go to a separate announcement with *http://localhost:4200/classrooms/3/announcements/7*. In my `app-routing` I have this:

```
{ path: 'classrooms/:classroomId', component: ViewClassroomComponent,
     children : [{path: 'announcements/:announcementId', component: AnnouncementDetailsComponent}] }
```

This approach is wrong because when I go to the *http://localhost:4200/classrooms/3/announcements/7* my **AnnouncementDetailsComponent** doesn't invoke. What is correct approach here?
This is my routing function:

```
open(announcementId: number){
    this.router.navigate(['/classrooms/' + this.classroomId + '/announcements', announcementId]); 
  }
```

Comment: Do you have a `<router-outlet>` somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me explain through code:

My router (you are using children which is ok too!):

```js
  {
    path: 'users/:username/class/:classroom',
    component: ClassroomComponent
  }
```

The url:

```js
/users/cris/class/coding
```

Here is a small example for you: https://angular-route-parameters-lmhcei.stackblitz.io/users/cris/class/coding

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-route-parameters-lmhcei?file=app%2Fapp-routing.module.ts

Seems you are missing one `.this` as well.

```js
open(announcementId: number){
    this.router.navigate(['/classrooms/' + this.classroomId + '/announcements', this.announcementId]); 
  }
```

Comment: `this.announcementId` gives error. Here my `announcementId` is a local variable.
`{ path: 'classrooms/:classroomId/announcements/:announcementId', component: AnnouncementDetailsComponent}` helped a lot, thank you.